# Why paymentID is null after PayPal transaction?

Tags: reactjs, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal in sandbox mode and [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) in my React application and I'm using .NET 5 as my REST API.
Here is my payload when I want to create an order:

```
{
  "totalAmount": 102,
  "tax": 0,
  "fee": 2,
  "paymentMethod": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "reciver": "vala",
      "phone": "0912351231",
      "email": "vala@gmail.com",
      "sender": "ali",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is part of my react code that call PayPal API:

```
<BoxPayment isRtl={isRtl}>
    <Text as="h3">{translations.buyPage.paymentMethodTitle}</Text>
    <Text as="p">{translations.buyPage.paymentMethodSubTitle}</Text>
    <div style={{ 'paddingTop': '.5rem' }}>
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
        <PayPalButtons createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
            onApprove={(data, actions: any) => {
            console.log('data', data);
            console.log('actions', actions);
            return actions.order.capture().then((details: any) => {
                console.log('details', details);
                const name = details.payer.name.given_name;
            });
            }} />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </div>
</BoxPayment>
```

But after successful payment here's what I receive when I console.log data object:

```
{
    "orderID": "48G91901G2470590C",
    "payerID": "NBPJH63GK5H5Q",
    "paymentID": null,
    "billingToken": null,
    "facilitatorAccessToken": "A11VAJ-tUcUqKkJgAhnyfVGVYg6Z57SvqHfspQqB8vtUDjDzBMIBlvO6rDvwdIjW7aJwvQQYeMAGyWitChtVZ8LyBzCw"
}
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `onApprove`, the order hasn't been captured when you are printing that data. Capture the order first.  When an order is captured, its transaction ID will be in the response's `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0]`

---

If you need to do anything important with that ID, such as store it in a database, used a server-side integration (***not*** actions.order.capture nor actions.order.create, client-side code is not for database operations).  See the optional step #5 in the 'Add and modify the code' section of the guide for [Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), and be sure to use the client-side error handling code in its linked [demo pattern example](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server).

Comment: My purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id is "802796486X456725H" shouldn't be something like "PAYID-MH4RTFI3YP27904FX424223N" ?

Comment: No, PAYIDs are only used by the previous v1/payments API.  The current v2/checkout/orders API uses an orderId instead for the approval process. And just like PAYIDs, the orderId is not useful once successfully captured, so there is no reason to keep either of these values.  Only this API's captureId (or in the previous v1 API, the saleId) are useful to keep.

Comment: Is there any way that I work with v1/payments again? cause I don't have access to the backend source code and I'm just refactoring the frontend

Comment: You can use the demo pattern of https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server with a v1/payments backend.  You'll likely need to fetch the EC token from createOrder , and then send some identifier along with the payerId back to trigger a v1/payments execute.  Don't use actions.order.create nor actions.order.capture , those functions are for using v2/checkout/orders with no backend.

Comment: If you're not supposed to use order.create's response on the server side, then why does it give a response at all? I'm certainly not gonna store all that in a client side cookie. Anyway, I'm trying to Payment.Get() server side, using the purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id. It gives me an error, saying the resource wasn't found. I've also tried the order id. I've also tried to prepend "PAY-". Nothing works. What can I do to get my server side payment verification to work?

Comment: Do I need to use the server pattern from this page (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), so I can capture a tx id on the server side, which I can then easily validate by checking its status? If so, why does the JS SDK even allow the whole order capture to happen client side, and you can't validate it server side? Seems to me like a user could hack the request in order to receive a higher priced product. Or repeatedly send the same request with the same tx id, to keep getting the product over and over again.

Comment: The client side functions are for very simple use cases. If you are storing anything on a server after payment completion, they should not be used. Create and capture on that server itself. The clientid+secret used on the server and the clientid used to load the JS SDK for approval must correspond. Resource not found is the expected error when they do not correspond.

Comment: Tnx, I'm slowly getting to where I need to be. So it looks like I need to use the server pattern from the link I provided, where I do order creation and capturing on the server side. This makes the payment flow a lot more like my already integrated Stripe payments. PayPal gave me the client side functions in a quickstart snippet, so I used them, thinking that's how to go about it. I wish the docs were clearer. Or maybe it's me. I'll double-checked whether the client ID on server and in client script are a match. They are. But still, Payment.Get() refuses to fetch me a Payment.